# How can I rotate a symbol around its center without specifying its position twice?

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms

I have some tile symbols that I would like to place on a grid. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Use tile coordinates to position the symbols (e.g. `4,2` instead of `85,43`)
- Use pixel coordinates (not tile coordinates) for defining the vertices of symbols
- Rotate symbols around their center without specifying absolute coordinates.

I have solutions to the first two (there might be better solutions though) but not the third. I can rotate the tile at `4,2` by a quarter turn with this:

```
<!-- 10/21 = 0.47619047619 -->
<use x="4" y="2" href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-0" transform="rotate(90 4.476 2.476)" />
```

I really don't like having to specify the tile coordinates twice. Ideally, I would like to write something like this instead:

```
<use x="4" y="2" href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-0 rotate-1" />
```

Defining `.rotate-1` in the stylesheet doesn't seem to have any effect on the rotation. `transform-origin="50% 50%"` seems to be setting the origin to `50%` of the viewport or something. Maybe defining the symbol with coordinates from `-10` to `10` instead of `0` to `20` would help? Should I define the `viewBox` of the symbols?

Another solution would be manually changing the coordinates of the vertices in the symbol to create the other 3 orientations. I'd rather not!

Anyway, this is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!-- 21*10+1 = 211 -->
<svg width="211" height="211" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .grid-line {
      fill: #DDD;
    }
    .grass-fill {
      fill: #8C8;
    }
    .tile {
      /* 1/21 = 0.04761904761 */
      transform: scale(0.04761904761, 0.04761904761);
    }
    
    .theme-0 {
      --roof-color-0: #F44;
      --roof-color-1: #F66;
      --roof-color-2: #F88;
      --roof-color-3: #FAA;
    }
    
    .theme-1 {
      --roof-color-0: #44F;
      --roof-color-1: #66F;
      --roof-color-2: #88F;
      --roof-color-3: #AAF;
    }
  </style>
  
  <defs>
    <pattern id="grid" width="21" height="21" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect class="grid-line" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="21" />
      <rect class="grid-line" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="1" />
    </pattern>
    
    <symbol id="rooftop-0">
      <g class="tile">
        <rect class="grass-fill" width="20" height="20" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-0)" points="3,2 17,2 18,8 2,8" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-1)" points="2,8 18,8 17,14 3,14" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-2)" points="8,8 11,14 11,18 8,18" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-3)" points="8,8 8,18 5,18 5,14" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
    
    <symbol id="rooftop-1">
      <g class="tile">
        <rect class="grass-fill" width="20" height="20" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-0)" points="2,11 18,11 17,17 3,17" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-1)" points="3,5 17,5 18,11 2,11" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-2)" points="10,11 10,3 13,3 13,5" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-3)" points="10,11 7,5 7,3 10,3" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  
  <g>
    <rect fill="#999" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <rect fill="url(#grid)" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </g>
  
  <g transform="translate(1, 1) scale(21, 21)">
    <use x="3" y="2" href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-1" />
    <!-- 10/21 = 0.47619047619 -->
    <use x="4" y="2" href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-0" transform="rotate(90 4.476 2.476)" />
    <use x="5" y="2" href="#rooftop-1" class="theme-1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a clean way of doing what I'm trying to do? Rotating a symbol around its center seems like something one would do all the time.

Comment: Yes! Add a viewBox attribute. Everything in an SVG is relative to the viewBox.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Where? What values? Could you explain?

Comment: Draw all your symbols so that their centre is at the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting your <use> attributes using `x`and `y` coordinates, you can set them using `transform="translate(x, y)`, this way, the origin parameters of the `rotate()` method will stay the same (`0.5, 0.5`):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 211 211">
  <style>
    .grid-line {
      fill: #DDD;
    }
    .grass-fill {
      fill: #8C8;
    }
    .theme-0 {
      --roof-color-0: #F44;
      --roof-color-1: #F66;
      --roof-color-2: #F88;
      --roof-color-3: #FAA;
    }

    .theme-1 {
      --roof-color-0: #44F;
      --roof-color-1: #66F;
      --roof-color-2: #88F;
      --roof-color-3: #AAF;
    }
  </style>

  <defs>
    <pattern id="grid" x="-0.5" y="-0.5" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect class="grid-line" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="20" />
      <rect class="grid-line" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="1" />
    </pattern>

    <symbol id="rooftop-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <g class="tile" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5) scale(0.95)">
        <rect class="grass-fill" width="20" height="20" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-0)" points="3,2 17,2 18,8 2,8" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-1)" points="2,8 18,8 17,14 3,14" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-2)" points="8,8 11,14 11,18 8,18" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-3)" points="8,8 8,18 5,18 5,14" />
      </g>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="rooftop-1" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <g class="tile"transform="translate(0.5, 0.5) scale(0.95)">
        <rect class="grass-fill" width="20" height="20" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-0)" points="2,11 18,11 17,17 3,17" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-1)" points="3,5 17,5 18,11 2,11" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-2)" points="10,11 10,3 13,3 13,5" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-3)" points="10,11 7,5 7,3 10,3" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  
  <g>
    <rect fill="#999" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <rect fill="url(#grid)" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </g>
  
  <g transform="scale(20, 20)">
      <use xlink:href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-1" width="1" height="1" transform="translate(4, 2) rotate(0,0.5,0.5)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#rooftop-1" class="theme-0" width="1" height="1" transform="translate(5, 2) rotate(90,0.5,0.5)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-1" width="1" height="1" transform="translate(6, 2) rotate(180,0.5,0.5)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Looks promising but the scale is off.

Comment: This is so close to what I want but the tiles are being scaled a tiny bit too big.

Comment: Yes sorry, had to change your grid so that it falls on the center of the coordinate system and modify your symbols so that they be 19units wide actually (to be able to fit in the 19units square blank left by the grid

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were asking: The symbol has now a `wiewBox` attribute: `viewBox="0 0 20 20"` This means that the symbol has a width of 20 units and a height of 20 units. Now you can use the symbol like this:

```
<use xlink:href="#rooftop-0"  width="20" height="20" x="63" y="21"  />
```

As you can see I can give the symbol a width and a height in this case width="20" height="20" but you can give it any size you need. Also you can use the x and y attributes to reposition the used symbol.

Now you can also rotate the use element around it's center by using `transform="rotate(90,73,31)"` This is rotating the element 90degs around the point {x:73,y:31}

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 211 211">
  <style>
    .grid-line {
      fill: #DDD;
    }
    .grass-fill {
      fill: #8C8;
    }
    
    .theme-0 {
      --roof-color-0: #F44;
      --roof-color-1: #F66;
      --roof-color-2: #F88;
      --roof-color-3: #FAA;
    }
    
    .theme-1 {
      --roof-color-0: #44F;
      --roof-color-1: #66F;
      --roof-color-2: #88F;
      --roof-color-3: #AAF;
    }
  </style>
  
  <defs>
    <pattern id="grid" width="21" height="21" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect class="grid-line" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="21" />
      <rect class="grid-line" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="1" />
    </pattern>
    
    <symbol id="rooftop-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <g class="tile">
        <rect class="grass-fill" width="20" height="20" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-0)" points="3,2 17,2 18,8 2,8" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-1)" points="2,8 18,8 17,14 3,14" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-2)" points="8,8 11,14 11,18 8,18" />
        <polygon style="fill: var(--roof-color-3)" points="8,8 8,18 5,18 5,14" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
    

  </defs>
  
  <g>
    <rect fill="#999" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <rect fill="url(#grid)" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </g>
  
  <g transform="translate(1, 1)">
    <use x="42" y="21" xlink:href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-1" width="20" height="20" />
    
    <use x="63" y="21" xlink:href="#rooftop-0" class="theme-0" width="20" height="20" transform="rotate(90,73,31)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'd prefer to write `x="3" y="1"` instead of `x="63" y="21"`. I'm asking how to rotate without specifying the position twice. I already know that I can set the origin with `rotate(90 73 31)` but I want to avoid writing the position twice.

Comment: Rotating a symbol around its center without writing the position twice seems to be impossible. Maybe I should give up on trying to build some kind of DSL and just use an image editor.

Comment: SVG may be human readable but it definitely seems like it's built for editing applications that don't mind doing math everywhere. That sucks.